# Look up Specs for AMD and Intel cpu's?

Tags: hardware, process

I once saw a page a page on Intel.com, where it was possible to look up a CPU, and e.g. see if it have VT.

Something similar to what AMD have
http://products.amd.com/en-us/DesktopCPUResult.aspx

Does anyone know the link for the Intel page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look here:

http://ark.intel.com

Select Processor and then the model you need.
Never saw a list of all processors, on the Intel website.

Comment: +1 - this tool used to be called processor finder and was located at processorfinder.intel.com.  That may have been what OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Intel is not as nice, and far more fond of segmenting the market by turning features on an off, for example, for VT, some cpu the same model may or may not have it, you have to look up the 5 digit code for that processor.